# $y'=\cos^7(y), y(3)=3$ Denote $y(x)$ as a solution, find its lower and upper bounds.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'=\cos^7(y), y(3)=3$.

$y(x)$ is a solution, find its lower and upper bounds.

**My solution :**

Denote $f(x,y)=\cos^7(y)$.

$f(x,y)\leq1 , f_y=-7\cos^6(y)\sin(y)\leq 7$.

$f(x,y) , f_y$ are bounded continues function.

Denote $B=\{(x,y)| |x-3|\leq a , |y-3|\leq b \}$ such that $B$ is a rectenagle , $M=1$.

Then,

The domain of the solution is $I=[3-\alpha,3+\alpha]$ such that $\alpha=\min\{ a,\frac{b}{m}\}=\{ a,b\}$.

Since $ a,b$ are bigger as I want , the domain is $-\infty < x < \infty$.

Now I have to find lower and upper bounds for the solution of the ode $y(x)$.

How can I find it ?

Help please.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation is autonomous and right side has roots. Each root represents a constant solution and thus a barrier for all other solutions. At $y=3$ the right side is about $-1$, so the solution is falling from the root above $3$ to the one directly below it.

Local existence and uniqueness are qualitative tools here, its proof construction is not needed as a quantitative one.

Comment: I reinsert my comment. The ODE is separable, and we can easily deduce that $y(+\infty) = \frac{\pi}{2} < y(x) < \frac{3\pi}{2} = y(-\infty)$

Comment: @ Lutz Lehmann +1 very elegant solution. I found explicitly that it holds by studying other positive integer exponents of $\cos(y)$

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze: One can make some other easy observations. For $y=\frac\pi2+u$, when $u\approx 0$, the equation is almost $u'=-u^7$, leading to $u(t)=u(T)\Bigl(1+6u(T)^6(t-T)\Bigr)^{-1/6}$, which converges slowly to $0$ for $t\to\infty$. Similarly for the other side.